# Grouping date ranges together

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to group date ranges together so I can sort my report by batch jobs. However the batch id repeats maybe twice per year so I have to group by date as well as batch ID. My dilemma is I am unable to get the range of batch IDs

Let’s say I have these date values

```
1/1/2021
5/1/2021
8/1/2021
3/7/2020
4/2/2019
```

I want to get

```
8/12/2020 - 8/1/2021
3/6/2020 - 3/7/2020
4/1/2019 - 4/2/2019
```

First time asking for help on Stack Overflow and on mobile. Forgive the formatting

Comment: This seems to be a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616860/sql-how-to-group-by-date-ranges

Comment: I’m trying to group by once a month while his was 2 days. Plus I can’t seem to use datetime as a datatype

Comment: I am totally lost on what the result set has to do with the sample data.  Dates are made up.  You say something occurs once or twice a year and then there are three rows for 2021.  Very confusing.

Comment: It looks like the given date data is in the form of `day/month/year`, and the start `day/month/year` is calculated based on the last `day/month/year` in each group via `MAX(x) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH`.  So the pairs would be `MAX(x) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH to MAX(x)`

Comment: I suspect the required result is going to cause problems by simply subtracting `1 MONTH` from the `MAX(x)` found in that month, causing overlap with actual dates found in the prior month.  My suggestion is to just use the start and end of each month group as the pairs or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68796867/grouping-date-ranges-together/68801592#comment121585619_68796867):

> I’m trying to group by once a month

Then use `GROUP BY TRUNC(date_column)` to group into calendar months.

```sql
SELECT batch_id,
       TRUNC(date_column) AS month,
       SUM(your_other_column) AS other_column_total
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY TRUNC(date_column);
```

If you want to group by a different range, i.e. from the 8th of the month until the 7th of the next month then use an offset:

```sql
SELECT batch_id,
       TRUNC(date_column - INTERVAL '7' DAY) AS month_from_8th,
       SUM(your_other_column) AS other_column_total
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY TRUNC(date_column - INTERVAL '7' DAY);
```

If you want to group by something else then you will need to define how to calculate the group ranges.